# TeXstudio on OSX install packages problem

Tags: packages, installing, texstudio, mac

I'm using TeXstudio, on Mac OS X El Capitan, and I'm writing my text using some template written in LaTeX. I'm having problems installing some missing packages, for instance:

1. babel support for serbian language
2. `upgreek.sty` is missing

I tried various solutions that I have found on the Internet, and I'm running out of the options.

Comment: you're missing the underlying engine. you only have the editor installed. you need to install a current version of either MacTeX or TeX Live.

Comment: Try installing first MacTeX, https://www.tug.org/mactex/, then texstudio.

Answer (score 2):

Real answer is using tlmgr command:

```
sudo tlmgr install package-name
```

Answer (score 1):

For OSX (now macOS) there is also separate version of TeXLive available, which is called [MacTex](http://tug.org/mactex/). The full installer comes with all packages (including `upgreek`, `babel-serbian` and `babel-serbianc`) and TeX Live Utility: a neat graphical front-end for `tlmgr` which allows installing and updating packages without the command line interface.